# Render a PHP template after get a window browser width

Tags: javascript, php

In some cases, I believe that is better render another layout template than to uses media queries for specifics devices. But, now, I need do this using PHP and Javascript.

On $screen variable, I'm getting the window broswer width, and, into the while, I  created a statement to render the better layout for client device. But, the PHP is not understanding the correct value of variable $screen and because this, not render the correct layout. Is a problem with the variable type (string) ?

```
<?php
    $screen = "<script>document.write(window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth)</script>";
    if ( $query->have_posts() ): 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
?>  
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"  title="<?php the_title();?>">
                <?php
                    if( $screen <= 767 ) { include( get_template_directory() . '/templates/home-card.php'); }
                    else { include( get_template_directory() . '/templates/search-horizontal-card.php'); }
                ?>
            </a>
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: I just using ajax to get the content of body. Like once the website is loaded trigger ajax call with the browser details to the server. Then render content on server accordingly and send to the browser accordingly.

Comment: The php has already finished processing before the html arrives at the browser and the javascript starts...

Comment: Well, is true, the two have reason. I will try follow the sugestion of Vivek. Thank you guys!